# My application does not have access to my Oracle 11g database sequence

Tags: oracle11g

I have sucessfully connected to my database through JDBC (no sid or service specified): `com.test.sql.url=jdbc:oracle:thin://@111.222.333.444:1521`, but when my java program tries to insert a row that uses a sequence I created, I get the error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`. I have verified in SQL developer that my sequences exist for my database user, so I'm thinking it is some kind of permissions issue? I initally created the user with sys as sysdba and then created a script that connected as the new user and created all the necessary tables and sequences. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @hol dbConnection.prepareStatement("select ticket_seq.NextVal from dual");

Comment: Do you need to set the schema? like `myschema.ticket_seq.next_val`

Comment: @hol I have tried manually (not in my application) with the schema, but it still says sequence does not exist (with a * under the t so it cant find ticket_seq) I have double checked the names and the sequence ticket_seq is visible in sql developer to the same user/password that my application uses. But I cannot select from it either when I am in sqlplus.

Comment: Also interesting, sequence also does not exist when I run the command `select userSchema.ticket_seq.nextval from dual` with sys as sysdba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was actually a problem with my database creation script. I had created the sequence with `CREATE SEQUENCE  "ticket_seq" START WITH 10;` so the double quotes enforced case sensitivity. I now know that Oracle tables/sequences, etc. are default case insensitive so the command `select ticket_seq.nextval from dual` was interpreted as `SELECT TICKET_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL` and therefore my lowercase sequence could not be found. I removed the double quotes from my script and now I can find the sequence as expected.